# Unchecked cast: Is there a way to avoid it in this case?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, unchecked

I have a situation that is causing an unchecked cast warning.  I know I can use supress warnings, but my instinct tell me there is a way to avoid it by changing how I've coded this snippet.  I can't, however, seem to get the solution to surface and could do with a fresh set of eyes.

```
//function removes elements from input, orders them and re-adds them
private <E extends Bus> int orderBuses(ArrayList<E> busList) {

  Bus busToAdd = null;

  ...

  busList.add((E) busToAdd);

  return 0;
}
```

The function is called with several lists, each containing a class that extends Bus.  Several functions are used on busToAdd that are part of Bus so using type E wouldnt work.

Any suggestions on how to restructure this without having to suppress warnings?

edit:  Found I can use E for busList, but end up having to cast the buses I assign to it which leads to the same warning.  I can try using E for all uses instead of Bus, I'll update when I have  tested it.

Comment: Since `E` extends `Bus`, it should support anything you want to do that requires a `Bus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace references to the type `Bus` by `E` in the body of your method. Then there would be no warning.

Example:

```
E busToAdd = busList.get(0);
// ...
busList.add(busToAdd);
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem was that it is assigned a Bus later before being used for various processing (I always initialise to null on declaration as habit).  This cannot be done without a cast as (E), and then we get the same warning.  It may be possible to change the way im processing the input to keep it in E form the whole way though?

Comment: Yes, you should keep the objects from the list in variables of type E the whole way through. Can't you just use different variables if you need to store objects of type Bus? Nothing what you wrote so far would require an unchecked cast anywhere in your method, so you should aim for that.

Comment: changed all references to Bus to use E and yes it does work.  Looking at it it makes sense to use the generic type variable rather than the supertype, quite likely this was the answer I could't bring to mind before.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't using `E` not work here?

You say that you're using some methods that are part of `Bus`, but since `E extends Bus` you should be able to call all of `Bus`' methods on `E` as well.